# Build Lite and Full Version of app

Tags: java, android, android-productflavors, android-build-type

I'm creating an app that will have a Lite and a Full version of it, one being free and the other having a small fee. Since I don't want to have to distinct projects to avoid updating errors (like updating a module in one version only) I set up a boolean in my Application class.

I was wondering how can I determine the value of that boolean with information from the app. I know I can create app with different Flavors and Build Types but I'm kind of lost in all that. Can you help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you're using Gradle and AndroidStudio, right?
You can create BuildConfig values for each flavor and/or buildType:

1. Goto your app/build.gradle file
2. If you prefer to put your variable at

a. buildType:

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
        versionNameSuffix "-beta"
        buildConfigField "Boolean", "PAYED", "false"
    }
}
```

b. flavor

```
productFlavors {
    premium {
        buildConfigField "Boolean", "PAYED", "true"
    }
}
```

And than, after a sync & build you can access those variables in your code depending on build/flavor you've chosen:

```
if (BuildConfig.PAYED) {
    // Do your stuff
    ...
}
```